# Filter my NSArray of NSDictionaries using several UIControls

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s (the dictionaries contain several key value pairs).  On my story board I have several `UISegmentedControl`s and during their selected events I'm filtering out my array of dictionaries (works lovely).  I'm storing the selected state and values of these SegmentedControls inside instance variables so I can tell if they were previously selected or being selected for the first time.

The problem I'm having is trying to filter this Array of Dictionaries using multiple predicates created by each `UISegmentControl`.  For example if I click SegmentControl 1 it filters the array accordingly, If I click SegmentControl 2 it takes the current result and filters those.  However if I choose another value from SegmentControl 1 it returns nothing, because all those values had been originally filtered out.  This is accentuated even more by the fact that I have 5 of these Segments and I need to make sure it can filter my unfiltered set that's generated on my `viewDidLoad` (my unfiltered data comes from a JSON source and is stored once when the app loads to prevent it pulling from JSON source multiple times).

I'm having a terrible time trying to solve this filter issue.  I'm not sure if it's because my brain is mush from looking at this all day or if it is my novice ability with objc (I've got a lot of oop program experience, but this is my first objective c app). I thought about originally making a function/method that accepts the unfiltered array, and all the selected filter values to return the filtered data but I can't wrap my head around what would happen if some of the filter fields were nil.  What is the best way to approach this?  Here is some code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    //Checks for UISegments
    Boolean isSegment1Selected;
    Boolean isSegment2Selected;
    Boolean isSegment3Selected;
    Boolean isSegment4Selected;

    //Instance FilterValues
    NSString *segment1Value;
    NSString *segment2Value;
    NSString *segment3Value;
    NSString *segment4Value;

    //Create arrays for dictionaries
    NSMutableArray *myArrayOfDictionaries;
    NSMutableArray *unfilteredArrayOfDictionaries;
    NSMutableArray *filteredArrayOfDictionaries;
}
@end
```

On my `viewDidLoad()` I'm filling `myArrayOfDictionaries` with the data from my JSON source.

I have IBOutlet events for each `UISegmentView` I'm using to filter.  I'll show you one since they are all pretty much the same minus their names:

```
/// UISegmentedControl Filters ///
- (IBAction)segment1:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    //    NSLog(isSegment1Selected ? @"YES" : @"NO");


    //Haven't used this if/else yet but guessing it will be part of the solution
    if (segment1Value == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Something");
    }

    //Grab value of SegmentControl into instance variable and strip additional characters not needed from the end
    segment1Value = [[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex] substringToIndex:[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex].length -1 ];


    //Create predicate filter with key and value
    NSPredicate *predicateForSegment1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", segment1_key, segment1Value];


    //Check if filteredArray already has objects
    if ([filteredArrayOfDictionaries count] == 0)
    {
        //If filteredArray is empty, fill it with the filtered data using predicate from selected Segmented index control.  Then clear the array and copy filtered array to filtered array
        filteredArrayOfDictionaries = [[unfilteredArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateForSegment1] mutableCopy];

    }
    else
    {

        //If filtered array is full, empty it first then fill it with new filtered values.
        NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:filteredArrayOfDictionaries];
        [filteredArrayOfDictionaries removeAllObjects];
        filteredArrayOfDictionaries = [[tmpArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateForImpellerDiameter] mutableCopy];


    }

    [myArrayOfDictionaries removeAllObjects];
    [myArrayOfDictionaries addObjectsFromArray:filteredArrayOfDictionaries];
    [tableData reloadData];

}
```

All of my `UISegmentControl`s look like this.  I started writing a function to call in each SegmentControl event to return the filtered array but I'm not sure if that is the best way either.  Here's what I have so far, I'm not sure if I should pass in Predicates or just Strings.

```
- (NSArray*)filteredResults:(NSArray*)unfilteredArray forSegment1:(NSPredicate*)segment1 forSegment2:(NSPredicate*)segment2 forSegment3:(NSPredicate*)segment3 forSegment4:(NSPredicate*)segment4;
```

Am I going about this the right way?  It all has become really confusing.  I know that when I select Segment1 and then Segment2, it filters correctly.  But as soon as I change the value of a segment already selected it returns nothing because the Segments values have already been filtered out by the first selection.  Is it possible to compare my filtered and my unfiltered array when a segment control has been previously selected?  I really hope this makes sense.  Thank you for looking and reading.

Comment: Try use: 
 NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: unfilteredArrayOfDictionaries];
instead :
NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: filteredArrayOfDictionaries];

Comment: But that will remove any filtering from any other selected Segment Controls, right?

Comment: sorry I can't get clearly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild the filtered array each time one of the segments changes.  I would use something like this

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    //Create arrays for dictionaries
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArrayOfDictionaries;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredArrayOfDictionaries;

    //Array for storage of predicates
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *predicates;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *predicateKeys;
}
@end



-(void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.predicateKeys=@[@"key1",@"key2",@"key3",@"key4",@"key4"];
     self.predicates=[NSMutableArray new];
     for (int i=0;i<self.predicateKeys.count;i++) {
         [self.predicates addObject:[NSNull null]];
     }
     [self setupFilteredArray];
}


//  Set the tag for each segmented controller to it's "number" - 0 to 5 and set this method as the action handler for all of the segmented controls


- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
      NSInteger segmentNumber=sender.tag;
//Grab value of SegmentControl into instance variable and strip additional characters not needed from the end
    segmentValue = [[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex] substringToIndex:[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex].length -1 ];

    if ([segmentValue isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self.predicates replaceObjectAtIndex:segmentNumber withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    else {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)",self.predicateKeys[segmentNumber], segmentValue];
        [self.predicates replaceObjectAtIndex:segmentNumber withObject:predicate];
    }

    [self setupFilteredArray];
}

-(void) setupFilteredArray {
    NSArray *tempArray=[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.myArrayOfDictionaries];
    for (int i=0;i<self.predicates.count;i++) {
        if (!([self.predicates[i] isEqual:[NSNull null]])) {
            NSPredicate *predicate=(NSPredicate *)self.predicates[i];
            tempArray=[tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        }
    }

    self.filteredArray=tempArray;  
}
```

Comment: When you say to set the tag for each segmentedcontrol, do you mean set it in the order it appears in the `predicateKeys` array?  Thank you by the way!

Comment: Ok figured that part out!  But it is still filtering my filtered results when changing the segmented view that is already selected.  I think this line: `tempArray=[tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`.  it's taking filtered values and filtering them again when changing the value of an already selected segment which returns nothing.

Comment: I think I need to check to see if the Segment being changed was previously selected so I can reload all of my unfiltered array.

Comment: `setupFilteredArray` starts by copying the unfiltered array and it then applies each predicate in turn, so changing the value for the first segmented control should reset first predicate value, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what is happening.  These are 2 of my segments I'm using:  http://i.imgur.com/qlo8Ytt.png  If I select 18" in the first segment and 3ph in the second it works great and filters appropriately.  However if I immediately change my selection in the first segment from 18 to 24, it shows no results (there should be) because I think it is trying to filter the filtered results, in which all the 24" results were already filtered out (does that make sense?).

Comment: I created a sample application using this approach and it works for me - Check the code here - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/5193ba2343d39326fe3e

Comment: In my UI each segmented control has the first value of "--" to allow deselection of the filter and for simplicity I just put the filter value in the title (no " or ph )

Comment: Ok so I made sure mine was setup the same as your (got the point about your -- and just using filter value) but it still does the exact same thing.  Setup a bucket for you to check my ViewController files in.  https://bitbucket.org/drpcken/px3/src/67e2b9caed5dbc9d4e4e9032c29699e36d6440a3/PX3/ViewController.m?at=Current  I'm so exhausted from this I can't even think straight :P  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: FINALLY got it I think!  So I added an Int that increments everytime a segmentedcontrol is selected or changed.  This will tell me if it was previously selected.  Then I added `if (segmentCheckCount > 1)` and if so then I would use my unfiltered array instead of reusing the filtered array.  Works perfectly with the predicate loop you showed me how to use.  THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63080/discussion-between-paulw11-and-drpcken).

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of how the MVC paradigm can quickly become a "Massive View Controller" architecture.

Your View Controller is now burdened with the responsibility of maintaining 5 separate data sources and managing the state between them. Poor guy!

What you should contemplate doing is implementing aggregated data sources and specifically in your case a segmented data source. This allows you to abstract all your data source logic into a model object where it belongs.

A segmented data source is responsible for managing child data sources as well as vending the appropriate selected data source. This type of design makes it significantly easier to change your code to include more arrays or remove arrays as you see fit.

The singular responsibility principle is your friend and abstraction should be very attractive as you notice your code exhibiting signs of code smell.

Want more to go on? Then I highly recommend watching this years WWDC talk on advanced collection view layouts, they discuss exactly how you can reduce your View Controller complexity and build reusable data sources. See [this blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apples-take-on-app-architecture/) for all the links

Comment: I love this answer.  I tried keeping everything abstract in the beginning but it was easier to solve 'problems' by just throwing it in the viewDidLoad.  So when you say DataSource you mean a separate class correct?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @drpcken glad to hear it! We are all guilty of making problems for future us to solve;) but what's important is being able to recognize when your simple solution is creating a bigger problem:) I did mean separate classes yes:)